# Node module export sub functions optimisation

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have two JS files:
main.js and app.js

I want to export/run with node.js functions from app.js into main.js.
Quite simple using module.exports and require('path/app')

The problem i encounter is that app.js countain many functions that depends from each others, some of the will have to wait for other to execute i want all of them to execute in order. It's like a mega function calculation.

So i decided to encapsulate all app.js in a major function called general() that i export to main.js. At first i found it easier to do so, but the way i have to write my code then makes me uncertain.

Is this a good way to do it and is it a good way to structure my app ?

The only solution i found is ton return each function in a big object and then call each sub function with ".subFunctionName()"

As i'm a novice i don't know if this a strange or common way to do it.
Am i over complicating it ? Are there easier way to do it for maintenance and performance ? Could it be better not to use a general function, and to export each function (that i need) ? If i export

Here my code :

main.js

```
const app = require('./app.js')

console.log('add1 to 5', app.general().add1(5)
/// return 5 so it works

console.log('add2 to 5', app.general().add2(5)
/// return 7 so it works
```

app.js

```
function general(){
     return {

       'fct1': function add1(x){
         return x + 1
       },
       'fct2': function add2(x){
         return this.fct1(x)+1
       }
     }
}

module.exports.general = general
```

Alternative without general() function

main.js

```
const app = require('./app.js')

console.log('add1 to 5', app.add1(5))
/// return 5 so it works

console.log('add2 to 5', app.add2(5))
/// return 7 so it works
```

app.js

```
function add1A (x) {
  x = x + 1
  return x
}


function add2A (x) {
  return (add1A(x) + 1)
}

module.exports = {
  add1A : add1A,
  add2A : add2A
}
```

Comment: Your `general` function doesn't seem to do anything but create an unnecessary object. There's no reason not to use the simple (second) approach. Unless that object contains any state, in which case you might prefer writing a `class` with methods though.

Comment: No class here. Thank you for your answer.